# How to set custom properties in an inherited control in xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, inheritance, uwp, custom-controls

I built a custom control TabularListView based on ListView with a new Property, an ObservableCollection of TabularListViewHeaderColumn.

**TabularListView:**

```
class TabularListView : ListView
{
    public TabularListView()
    {
        Columns = new ObservableCollection<TabularListViewHeaderColumn>();
    }
    public ObservableCollection<TabularListViewHeaderColumn> Columns
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<TabularListViewHeaderColumn>)GetValue(ColumnsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ColumnsProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ColumnsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Columns", typeof(ObservableCollection<TabularListViewHeaderColumn>), typeof(TabularListView), new PropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<TabularListViewHeaderColumn>()));
}
```

**TabularListViewHeaderColumn:**

```
class TabularListViewHeaderColumn : ContentControl
{
    public string Title
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TitleProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TitleProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TitleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Title", typeof(string), typeof(TabularListViewHeaderColumn), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));

    public string MappingName
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(MappingNameProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MappingNameProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MappingNameProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MappingName", typeof(string), typeof(TabularListViewHeaderColumn), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));
}
```

I try to use it like shown below, setting the TabularListViewHeaderColumns directly in XAML:

```
<Controls:TabularListView>
    <Controls:TabularListView.Header>
        <ItemsControl>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Content="{Binding Title}" Width="{Binding Width}"
                            FontWeight="Bold"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Controls:TabularListView.Header>
    <Controls:TabularListView.Columns>
        <Controls:TabularListViewHeaderColumn Title="Test" MappingName="Inactive" Width="60"/>
        <Controls:TabularListViewHeaderColumn Title="Articlenumber" MappingName="DeviceType.ArticleNo" Width="170"/>
        <Controls:TabularListViewHeaderColumn Title="Serialnumber" MappingName="SerialNo" Width="170"/>
        <Controls:TabularListViewHeaderColumn Title="Inventorynumber" MappingName="EndCustNo" Width="170"/>
        <Controls:TabularListViewHeaderColumn Title="Description" MappingName="DeviceType.Description1" Width="300"/>
    </Controls:TabularListView.Columns>

</Controls:TabularListView>
```

Usualy when creating a regular Custom Control like in this example https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/32828.uwp-how-to-create-and-use-custom-control.aspx , I need to bind the respected property to the DependencyProperty, but since I only inherit from ListView and don't have any Xaml, I'm quiet confused how to do so.

Comment: A few things to note: 1. Don't do anything inside a setter of a dp, do it in its property changed callback. 2. Don't inherit from `Grid`, try `ContentControl` instead. 3. You should be doing any xaml related stuff for your custom controls in *Themes/Generic.xaml*.

Comment: I changed the Code as you told me, but now I get an error at initialize component

Comment: If you could create a repo for me that'd be a lot easier.